# Error deploying into Kubernetes EKS cluster from Jenkins pipeline using kubernetes-cd plugin

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks

I am facing issue to deploy into EKS kubernetes from Jenkins pipeline.

I am using kuberneter-cd plugin and getting following error

```
Loading configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jhipprojectmono/kubedeploy.yaml
Api call failed with code 403, detailed message: {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "deployments.apps \"jhipprojectmono\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"deployments\" in API group \"apps\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "jhipprojectmono",
    "group": "apps",
    "kind": "deployments"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I do understand this is for jenkins user do not have permission. I have created the service role for jenkins ..but still it is not working .. Attaching the kubeconfig for reference also.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1...
    server: https://xxxx.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:yyyy:cluster/finmanagercluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:yyyy:cluster/finmanagercluster
    namespace: default
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:yyyy:cluster/finmanagercluster
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:yyyy:cluster/finmanagercluster
- context:
    cluster: finmanagercluster
    user: jenkins
  name: finmanagercluster-context
- context:
    cluster: ""
    namespace: default
    user: jenkins
  name: gce
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:yyyy:cluster/finmanagercluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:yyyy:cluster/finmanagercluster
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - finmanagercluster
      command: aws
      env: null
```

Anything I am missing

I am using kubernetes-CD plugin ..

Comment: You are not authenticating as `jenkins` user. `User \"system:anonymous\"` suggests that you are not authenticating at all. Please double check your configuration. Is your jenkins running in kubernetes?

Comment: No Allner .. My jenkins is not inside kubernetes .. it is a separate standalone server (EC2  Linux AMI) ..thats why I am not able to understand how to configure it accordingly.

Comment: @ajoysinha Have you solved the above issue? Please let me know how

Comment: Sorry, Kubernetes-CD plugin didn't work for me, hence I took the vanilla approach ..  using 'sh apply XXX.yaml -n namespace' ..

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but below would help, if you have jenkins on EC2 (I mean within AWS).

Create a Role with below (called it ec2role) and attach it to EC2 where your Jenkins is running

1. Select AWS Service  "Trusted entity type"
2. Select EC2 under "Common use cases"
3. EKS permissions like below, it is for all policies(you can change as per your need)

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "eks.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now with a user who created EKS cluster or user who has access to modify configmap, do following actions(below is to act as a admin but you can specify as per your need with RBAC)

```
kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth
```

add below

```
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/ec2role
      username: ec2role
      groups:
      - system:masters
```

save and exit.

It should work.